# Conflict in gosec results in golangci-lint tool

Tags: go, resultset, conflict, security-testing

I am trying to [gosec](https://github.com/securego/gosec) in [golangci-lint](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint). However, some issues that are reported in gosec do not get reported when using gosec through golangci-lint.

I've used https://github.com/golang/example project. There were 3 issues reported when running goses.

```
$ gosec gotypes
[gosec] 2020/11/12 13:56:09 Including rules: default
[gosec] 2020/11/12 13:56:09 Excluding rules: default
[gosec] 2020/11/12 13:56:09 Import directory: personal/sec-test-go/example/gotypes
[gosec] 2020/11/12 13:56:09 Checking package: main
[gosec] 2020/11/12 13:56:09 Checking file: personal/sec-test-go/example/gotypes/weave.go
Results:
[personal/sec-test-go/example/gotypes/weave.go:106] - G304 (CWE-22): Potential file inclusion via variable (Confidence: HIGH, Severity: MEDIUM)
    105: func include(file, tag string) (string, error) {
  > 106:    f, err := os.Open(file)
    107:    if err != nil {
[personal/sec-test-go/example/gotypes/weave.go:110] - G307 (CWE-703): Deferring unsafe method "Close" on type "*os.File" (Confidence: HIGH, Severity: MEDIUM)
    109:    }
  > 110:    defer f.Close()
    111:
[personal/sec-test-go/example/gotypes/weave.go:30] - G307 (CWE-703): Deferring unsafe method "Close" on type "*os.File" (Confidence: HIGH, Severity: MEDIUM)
    29:     }
  > 30:     defer f.Close()
    31:
Summary:
   Files: 1
   Lines: 191
   Nosec: 0
  Issues: 3
```

However, when I run the same code with gosec using golangci-lint none of the issues were recorded.

But when I ran both of the tools for another set of codes (another directory in the sample code), all the issues were recorded.

```
$ golangci-lint run outyet --disable-all -E gosec
outyet/main.go:98:12: G107: Potential HTTP request made with variable url (gosec)
    r, err := http.Head(url)

$ gosec outyet
[gosec] 2020/11/12 14:07:56 Including rules: default
[gosec] 2020/11/12 14:07:56 Excluding rules: default
[gosec] 2020/11/12 14:07:56 Import directory: personal/sec-test-go/example/outyet
[gosec] 2020/11/12 14:07:56 Checking package: main
[gosec] 2020/11/12 14:07:56 Checking file: sec-test-go/example/outyet/main.go
Results:

[personal/sec-test-go/example/outyet/main.go:98] - G107 (CWE-88): Potential HTTP request made with variable url (Confidence: MEDIUM, Severity: MEDIUM)
    97:     pollCount.Add(1)
  > 98:     r, err := http.Head(url)
    99:     if err != nil {

Summary:
   Files: 1
   Lines: 140
   Nosec: 0
  Issues: 1
```

Did anyone encounter this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Golangci-lint has default settings to reduce the amount of false positives.

Try the --exclude-use-default=false parameter.

```
golangci-lint run outyet --disable-all --exclude-use-default=false -E gosec
```